# Is Ed pronounced differently from Edd?

Tags: pronunciation, names

Are the nicknames Ed and Edd pronounced differently? I'm curious about this because of the cartoon *Ed, Edd n Eddy*.

Comment: "Edd" isn't a real name or a nickname. It's made up for the cartoon. You should watch the cartoon and listen to how they pronounce it. If you have already watched the show and can't tell if the pronunciation is different, please edit your question to indicate this.

Comment: Some sounds that are different in your native language might sound the same to foreigners. That's why questions like this are asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be no difference in pronunciation "Edd" is just a spelling variant of "Ed" and short for names like Edgar, Edmund, Edward and Edwin.  The "Ed" element in these names is an Old English word meaning "wealth" and the "Ed" names meant things like "Wealthy Soldier" or "Wealth protector".